# Resctricting access to only 1 ip address and console connection

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, ssh, console, connection

I havent found an answer to this situation, and I'd like to have an answer before trying it and be stuck !

I would like to restrict connection to my EC2 instance to SSH from one IP address. Also I wonder if connecting to this instance within the console (Amazon website) would be prohibited ?
In other words, suppose I usually connect to this instance through a proxy or a VPN. Would I be able to connect to this instance, change parameters, etc. through the amazon website from any place ? In case the proxy or VPN breaks down ?
This may seems a silly question, but I'm not a specialist and I wouldn't like to be stuck outside :)

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict SSH access to an Amazon EC2 instance by creating a **Security Group** that only permits Inbound SSH (port 22) access from a specific IP address.

The Security Group only limits access to the instance itself. Any activity in the **EC2 management console** (eg stopping and starting an instance) is *not* impacted by Security Group settings.

You cannot "connect to an instance from the Amazon EC2 console", but the console does have the ability to launch **EC2 Instance Connect**, which is a web-based SSH. However, it cannot be restricted to one IP address.

Comment: Thanks. Very clear !